# Changing image of CCSprite changes its size?

Tags: ios, image, switch-statement, ccsprite

I am trying to have a CCSprite be the album artwork sprite for when my iPod music plays but the problem is, when I change the image from the NoImage.png to the actual album artwork, the CCSprite seems to change size and the image is smaller than the CCSprite originally was. I honestly cannot see why this is happening but maybe someone else will!

Anyway here is how I create the CCSprite in the init method,

```
albumArtwork = [[[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"NoImage.png"] autorelease];
        [albumArtwork setScaleX:159 / albumArtwork.contentSize.width];
        [albumArtwork setScaleY:139 / albumArtwork.contentSize.height];
        albumArtwork.position = ccp(320/2, 190);
        [self addChild:albumArtwork z:26];
```

Then when the iPod music starts I do this to change the CCSprite image from the NoImage.png to the iPod song artwork:

```
UIImage *albumArtworkImage = NULL;
    MPMediaItemArtwork *itemArtwork = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    if (itemArtwork != nil) {
        albumArtworkImage = [itemArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(albumArtwork.contentSize.width, albumArtwork.contentSize.width)];
    }

    if (albumArtworkImage) {
        CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addCGImage:albumArtworkImage.CGImage forKey:@"albumArtwork"];
        [albumArtwork setTexture: tex];
    } else { // no album artwork
        CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"NoImage.png"];
        [albumArtwork setTexture:tex];
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and if so, how could I fix it?

**Edit2**:
This is what I condensed it down to:

```
CCTexture2D *tex;
    MPMediaItemArtwork *itemArtwork = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    if (itemArtwork) {
        UIImage *albumArtworkImage = NULL;
        UIImage *firstImage = [itemArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(159.0f, 139.0f)];
        albumArtworkImage = [firstImage resizedImage:CGSizeMake(albumArtwork.contentSize.width, albumArtwork.contentSize.height) interpolationQuality: kCGInterpolationHigh];
        albumArtworkImage = [albumArtworkImage roundedCornerImage:8 borderSize:4]; 
        tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addCGImage:albumArtworkImage.CGImage forKey:@"albumArtwork"];
    } else { // no album artwork
        tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"NoImage.png"];
    }
    [albumArtwork setTexture:tex];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (albumArtworkImage) {
    CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addCGImage:albumArtworkImage.CGImage forKey:@"albumArtwork"];
    [albumArtwork setTexture: tex];
} else { // no album artwork
    CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"NoImage.png"];
    [albumArtwork setTexture:tex];
}
// reset visual size after you set new texture:
[albumArtwork setScaleX:159 / albumArtwork.contentSize.width];
[albumArtwork setScaleY:139 / albumArtwork.contentSize.height];
```

This means that your sprite always will be rendered with size 159x139 pixels independently of image size.

Comment: Look at my Edit1, I am not using my itemArtwork variable which I should be. You seemed to left out that part :P

Comment: I think it has to do with the MPMediaItemArtwork not resizing like they say in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667631/mpmediaitemartwork-returning-wrong-sized-artwork

Do you know how I could resize it to that it is 159, 139? Thanks!